# Launch program default enable Installshield

Tags: installshield

I have installshield project with launch program at the end .
But the checkbox is unchecked default. but i need to check the checkbox by default.

Thanks

Comment: Try assigning a value of 1 to the property attached to the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

By default the checkbox (launch program) on the setup complete dialog will not be selected. To select it automatically add the property LAUNCHPROGRAM to the **property table** and set it to a value of '1'.